# Passing Variable as parameter in onclick method in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, parameters, anchor

I am writing a html in where the html will display a list of records with three fields - id, name and an icon. When the icon will be clicked by user, a method will be called where the id will be passed as parameter and details of that record will be returned. The code snipped I am following is as below -

```
<tr *ngFor="let userDetail of userDetails">
                  <td>{{ userDetail.id }}</td>
                  <td>{{ userDetail.firstname }}  {{userDetail.lastname}}</td>
                  <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" (click) = "showUserDetails()" ><img src="/assets/user_details.png" width="20" height="20" /></a></td>
                </tr>
```

Here I need to pass the userDetail.id when the showUserDetails() function will be created. But still unable to pass the parameter.
What will be best way to pass that parameter?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know Angular from squat so I probably shouldn't even comment, but I can't stop myself!! Would it not be: `(click) = "showUserDetails({{ userDetail.id }})"`

Comment: Simply use showUserDetails(userDetail.id).

Comment: (click) = "showUserDetails(userDetail.id)"

Comment: Tried both of those options...but it didn't work...

Comment: @javadeveloper which one?

Comment: strange.. working in sandbox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-sky-4jfb7

Answer (score 4):

You have to make sure:

1. You are passing the value into the method:`(click) = "showUserDetails(userDetails.id)"`
2. The method should be declared in the same component otherwise you have to bind e.g. the service it's implented in within a public variable in the components constructor.

I created a simple [stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pass-data-to-method-inside-ngfor). that may can help you.